# Can odd or even parity correct errors

Tags: network

Can odd or even parity correct errors?
Odd or even parity can be used to detect errors. Can it correct errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parity use to detect errors, not for correcting.Especially it is used to validate Integrity of Data. If parity check is failed in receiver's end frame will be rejected.

Read [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-a-parity-bit) article for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Single-bit parity can only detect errors and it can only detect *single-bit errors*. Multi-bit errors can cancel each other out, resulting in undetected errors. In information theory, a single bit can only hold the simple information "data correct" or "data incorrect".

Using multi-bit ECC codes on larger bit groups is far superior as it can correct single-bit errors and detect a number of multi-bit errors.

At the end of the day, the ECC/FEC overhead length defines or limits the amount of error correction and detection you can get - the more, the better. For starters, check out [Hamming code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code), and for a different approach *Tomlinson-Harashima precoding* or [dirty paper coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirty_paper_coding) in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **multidimensional** parity to correct errors, but the amount of error-correction you get is low for a given amount of parity overhead.  This makes it suitable only for situations with very low bit error rates.

A two-dimensional parity scheme can correct a single error:

```
Original      With error     Correction
1 0 1 1  1    1 0 1 1  1     0 0 0 0  0
0 1 0 1  0    0 0 0 1  0 E   0 1 0 0  0
1 0 0 0  1    1 0 0 0  1     0 0 0 0  0
0 0 0 0  0    0 0 0 0  0     0 0 0 0  0
0 1 1 0  0    0 1 1 0  0     0 0 0 0  0
                E
```

You can see that a single bit error correction of MxN bits uses M+N+1 bits of parity.

[Hamming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code) codes can be considered a variety of multidimensional parity.

There are many, many, error correction/detection schemes with very varying properties, often with quite beautiful mathematics behind them: I'm particularly fond of [Golay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Golay_code) and [Verhoeff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verhoeff_algorithm).  Some details of error correction schemes are best followed up in Mathematics (for theory) or Electronics (for implementation) stackexchanges.